# Using config.gem causes an error on RoR application start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rubygems, newrelic

I'm trying to use newrelic in my project. I've installed newrelic gem successfully and the next step was adding config.gem "newrelic_rpm" to environment.rb

When I use config.gem in environment.rb I'm getting **Ruby on Rails application could not be started** However using *config.gem "dfgdsgsdgsdfg"* causes the same error.

How can I solve the problem?

I'm running Debian Linux, Apache2, RVM 1.8.6, Passenger 3, Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7, gem 1.8.10

Here is my environment.rb

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

config.gem "newrelic_rpm"


config.time_zone = 'UTC'

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_content_type = "text/html"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.xxx.xx",
    :port => 25,
    :domain => "xxxx.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "site@xxxxx.com",
    :password => "xxxxx"
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
end
```

and full backtrace

```
Ruby on Rails application could not be started


Error message:
    undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String
Exception class:
    NoMethodError
Application root:
    /var/www/ytndweb/data/www/rc.xxxx.xx 
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb    268     in `=='
1   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb     217     in `==='
2   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb     217     in `matching_specs'
3   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb     36  in `find_all'
4   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb  410     in `each'
5   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb  409     in `each'
6   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb     216     in `find_all'
7   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb     216     in `matching_specs'
8   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb     238     in `to_specs'
9   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb     256     in `to_spec'
10  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb    1210    in `gem'
11  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb    73  in `add_load_paths'
12  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb     301     in `add_gem_load_paths'
13  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb     301     in `each'
14  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb     301     in `add_gem_load_paths'
15  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb     132     in `process'
16  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb     113     in `send'
17  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb     113     in `run'
18  /var/www/ytndweb/data/www/rc.yetonado.ru/config/environment.rb  10  
19  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb     36  in `gem_original_require'
20  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb     36  in `require'
21  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb     222     in `preload_application'
22  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb     181     in `initialize_server'
23  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb     572     in `report_app_init_status'
24  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb     174     in `initialize_server'
25  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204     in `start_synchronously'
26  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180     in `start'
27  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb     149     in `start'
28  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     219     in `spawn_rails_application'
29  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132     in `lookup_or_add'
30  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     214     in `spawn_rails_application'
31  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in `synchronize'
32  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in `synchronize'
33  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     213     in `spawn_rails_application'
34  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     132     in `spawn_application'
35  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     275     in `handle_spawn_application'
36  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357     in `__send__'
37  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357     in `server_main_loop'
38  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206     in `start_synchronously'
39  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server  99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface: I work for New Relic.

Instead of using config.gem just add:

```
 require "newrelic_rpm"
```

after the initializer and it should work just fine :) I wish I had a reason why you have to do it that way, but I don't. It's just an ol' trick I remember when I was still working on Rails 2.x apps (I never had good luck with config.gem).